# Picking PDF document in swift3

Tags: pdf, swift3

I tried to pick, pdf document in swift3, but unable to pick pdf document. please check my code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIDocumentPickerDelegate, UIDocumentMenuDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {
@IBAction func clickAction(_ sender: Any) {
        let picker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [kUTTypePDF as String], in: .import)
        picker.delegate = self
        present(picker, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }
  func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL){
     let fileText = try NSString(contentsOf: url, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        print(fileText)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the following method :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UIDocumentMenuDelegate,UIDocumentPickerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {
        @IBAction func clickAction(_ sender: Any) {
            self.p_documentclicked()
        }

        fileprivate func p_documentclicked() {
            let importMenu = UIDocumentMenuViewController(documentTypes: ["public.text", "public.data","public.pdf", "public.doc"], in: .import)
            importMenu.delegate = self
            self.present(importMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    internal func documentMenu(_ documentMenu:     UIDocumentMenuViewController, didPickDocumentPicker documentPicker: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {

            documentPicker.delegate = self
            self.present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }



        func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {

            print("we cancelled")
        }

        internal func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {
            let cico = url as URL
            print(cico)
            self.load(URL: cico as NSURL)
        }

        fileprivate func load(URL: NSURL) {
            let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
            let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)
            var request = URLRequest(url: URL as URL)
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
            let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
                if (error == nil) {
                    // Success
                    let statusCode = response?.mimeType
                    print("Success: \(String(describing: statusCode))")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        self.p_uploadDocument(data!, filename: URL.lastPathComponent!)
                    })

                    // This is your file-variable:
                    // data
                }
                else {
                    // Failure
                    print("Failure: %@", error!.localizedDescription)
                }
            })
            task.resume()
        }
}
```